# How to build/use sharpen from XobotOS?

Tags: c#, java, android, sharpen-tool, xobotos

I cloned git://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS.git and followed instructions from https://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS/blob/master/sharpen/README

Apparently mono's team has pre built version which readme instructions are related since adding provided site directory does not adds sharpen plugin to available in "Install new software" dialog in eclipse. I guess it has to be built.

So how to build this eclipse plugin? It does not seem to have any ant/maven files.

Comment: ops. found README.build at the root. will try follow instructions there

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Eclipse 3.4 http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-342/ganymedesr2

However I have errors in source.

Comment: it looks like JDT classes are not on build path

Comment: i managed to build plugins and run eclipse eclipse debugging session by using eclipse classic 3.7.2 and adding "Plugin dependencies" library in Java Build Path/Libraries project properties. Needed only for sharpen.core.

Comment: You may find some additional input to this issue in my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10618492/650012 . According to Miguel de Icaza, the XobotOS Sharpen is currently not particularly suited for conversion of arbitrary Java projects, for that purpose he recommends Lluis Sanchez' Sharpen version instead: https://github.com/slluis/sharpen