# Using Sharpen and eclipse : error "Application "sharpen.core.application" could not be found in the registry."

Tags: c#, java, converters, sharpen-tool

### Background

I'm currently doing a benchmark of solutions to convert java code to c#
We have a fast evolving java software and wan't to port some low level (not ui) apis with a tool, because maintaining all changes between versions could prove really tiresome...
Anyway, I've been trying to use Sharpen, as I heard it's a pretty wicked tool used by some mono "freaks" to keep some versions of their tools in check.

### What I did

- For this purpose, I tried several tutorials I found on internet, the easiest to understand being http://www.pauldb.me/post/14916717048/a-guide-to-sharpen-a-great-tool-for-converting-java
- As the link he gives for a pre-build sharpen plugin is now broken, I build my own version of the plugin using sources and instructions found here : https://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS/

### Result

The plugin build perfectly, and is installed in my eclipse folder. But when I try to run the ant script after setting everything up, I get an error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "sharpen.core.application" could not be found in the registry.

### Conclusion

Well. I'm lost here.
I have no idea what that means.

- I'm using Windows 7 64bit
- I'm using Eclipse 3.7
- I'm using java 6 sdk 64 bit

If anyone ran into this and has a solution... That be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially I tried the same approach as you did, with the same result. But if you follow the instructions in the [README.build](https://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS/blob/master/README.build) file, section *Setting things up*, you should be able to launch a secondary Eclipse applications with the sharpen.core and sharpen.xobotos plug-ins included.

You could then import your Java project subject to conversion into the secondary Eclipse app, provided that you have included a Sharpen Xobot builder command and nature into your project file, like this [.project](https://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS/blob/master/android/.project) file in the XobotOS/android folder. I edited the .project file manually before importing the project, but I assume you can also configure this from within Eclipse?

The configuration files provided by [Paul Du Bois](http://www.pauldb.me/post/14916717048/a-guide-to-sharpen-a-great-tool-for-converting-java) are not applicable, instead you will need to copy and edit the [converter-config.xml](https://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS/blob/master/android/converter-config.xml) file from the XobotOS/android folder. This file in turn references a file in the *app* sub-folder, which probably also needs to be copied and edited.

This is basically as far as I have been able to take it until now. I have been able to edit the configuration files to enable the converter to run, but at this point I have only been able to generate C# stubs. If you or someone else manages to take this even further, I would be happy to learn how to generate real C# files using the XobotOS Sharpen converter.

**UPDATE**

Asked Miguel de Icaza if there were any instructions for converting arbitrary Java projects using the XobotOS Sharpen version. He responded that there are many hard-coded details in this version that makes it difficult to apply to arbitrary projects. At this stage he recommends [Lluis Sanchez' Sharpen](https://github.com/slluis/sharpen) version to be used instead.

BTW, the NGit library has been moved to [here](https://github.com/mono/ngit). You will find a fully functional [sharpen plug-in](https://github.com/mono/ngit/blob/master/gen/plugins/sharpen.core_1.0.0.jar) for Eclipse in the gen/plugins sub-folder.

**UPDATE MAY 17**

Note that you need to have the *Plug-in Development Environment* software installed in Eclipse to be able to build and run the plug-in projects. IF you are running *Eclipse IDE for Java (SE) Developers*, you need to extend it with the PDE software.

Comment: Actually, I had some success ! I found out that I installed the plugin wrongly, hense Eclipse reaction. I have tried so many versions of sharpen that some conflict arose. In the end, I cleaned everything, then made it work with lluis sharpen, and xobotos sharpen. If you don't wan't stub, you have to use every package as namespace in the converter-config.xml file... Well, that the solution I came up with, there might be other ways.

Comment: Interesting! I will try out your approach as soon as possible and see if I too can avoid stubs. Thanks!

Comment: Men, was I tired : my sentence above isn't proper English :P Add (and not use) every package as a namespace, in the api-def.xml file, with something like that : <namespace name="com.redwarp.test" output="/output/sharpen"> The output will tell how it should be treated. If you want no docs, you will put output="/output/sharpen-no-docs", etc...

Comment: @Redwarp, I'm glad you figured out how to do this, but I'm still lost. I've copied the `sharpen.core_1.0.0.jar` file from ngit to Eclipse's `plugin` folder, but I have no idea how to actually use it from within Eclipse. This whole ordeal has made me hate Java development more than I imagined possible before. Everything on db4o's pages are outdated and incomplete and I can't find any tutorial on how to do everything required to convert a simple `.java` file to a `.cs` file. :(